# How to create automated web api from sql trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am writing to seek advice to what approach and process to consider/or take, for creating a web api, which calls new data record automatically from the database table, when database table(db.data) is updated with a new data record.

Having done some research, I have only come up with creating sql trigger which can get data, from the db.data, database table, when the table is updated/after insert.  After that, I am little unsure, how to connect that to web-api, if even possible to do so.

Any advice or suggestion would be very much appreciated, in what steps this task involve.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend .NET CLR Triggers. This is code you write in .NET (i.e. C#) which is then loaded into SQL Server and can be executed just as classic SQL trigger.

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093(SQL.90).aspx